# Unrolled Linked Lists and Skip Lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, skip-lists

Does anyone have a good resource to refer to for Unrolled Linked Lists and Skip Lists.

I just came across the two and can't get the hang of them. I am referring to Data Structures and Algorithms made easy by Narsimha Karumanchi. Although a good book, I do not understand the two kind of lists properly.

So if someone can explain the two and advantages with the help of a realistic use case, it would be really nice.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, these two websites are good as explanatory sources:
Opendatastructures and geeksforgeeks.
http://opendatastructures.org/ods-python/4_2_SkiplistSSet_Efficient_.html
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unrolled-linked-list-set-1-introduction/